# How to update or refresh comboBox item with button.add_click function in PowerShell?

Tags: winforms, powershell, button, combobox, refresh

I use a `ComboBox` to get a directory.  I need to update the directory by using the `Button.Click` event.

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '400,400'
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$ComboBox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox1.width                 = 100
$ComboBox1.height                = 20
$ComboBox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(36,60)
$ComboBox1.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$list = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name
foreach ($lst in $list) {
    $ComboBox1.Items.Add($lst)
}
$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "update"
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(182,60)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Button1.Add_Click({
})

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($ComboBox1,$Button1))
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update the directory"?  Are you making changes to the `ComboBox` items that you want synced back to the filesystem?  Or you want to repopulate the `ComboBox` with up-to-date directory information?

Comment: I wan to make a changes to the ComboBox items that I want synced back to the filesystem @BACON

Comment: So you want to be able to select a directory in the `ComboBox`, edit its properties, and click the `Button` to save those changes back to disk?  What properties do you want to edit?  Aside from the `ComboBox` itself, there are no controls in your code to display/edit directory properties.

Comment: My expectation, once I click `$Button1`, the `$ComboBox1` items will be updated depends on the directory path. Because the path that `$ComboBox` to get the directory is updated somtime

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you want to do.  Your comments seem to contradict each other.  You want to apply what's in your form to the directory, or apply what's in the directory to your form?  Either way it seems that you'll need more controls than you have here, unless the name of each directory is all you want to display.

Comment: Sorry for that. I mean I want to apply what's in the directory to my form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203443/discussion-between-sbr-and-bacon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are populating the `ComboBox` with this...

```bsh
$list = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name
foreach ($lst in $list) {
    $ComboBox1.Items.Add($lst)
}
```

It *sounds like* you want clicking the `Button` to simply do that again so the `ComboBox` will contain an up-to-date list of directories.  In that case your `Click` event handler should be created like this...

```bsh
$Button1.Add_Click({
    # Remove all items from the ComboBox
    $ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

    # Repopulate the ComboBox, just like when it was created
    $list = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name
    foreach ($lst in $list) {
        $ComboBox1.Items.Add($lst)
    }
})
```

[`Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.clear) is called first so you don't end up with duplicate directory items.

By the way, you can simplify this...

```bsh
$list = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name
foreach ($lst in $list) {
    $ComboBox1.Items.Add($lst)
}
```

...to this...

```bsh
$list = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name
$ComboBox1.Items.AddRange($list)
```

...or even this...

```bsh
$ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(@(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name)
```

Comment: Yes, you made it @BACON. Thank you so much. its great!